# Another Parse 'success/error not called' error

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, push-notification, httprequest

I recently posted an issue I had with another Parse CloudCode method, were the error was thrown that ***Error: success/error was not called***. I am having that issue again but with a different method/scenario.

`Parse.Cloud.define("background", function(request, response) {
var moments = require("cloud/moments.js");

    var now = moments.moment();


    var query = new Parse.Query("Group");

    query.find({
        success: function(results) {

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var object = results[i];
                var events = object.get("Events");

                var getUsers = false;

                for (var q = 0; q < events.length; q++) {
                    var e = events[q];

                    if (e.get("date") == now) {
                        getUsers = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (getUsers == true) {


                    for (var q = 0; q < events.length; q++) {
                        var e = events[q];

                        if (e.get("date") == now) {
                            var relation = object.relation("created");
                            var partOne = e.get("name");
                            var outString1 = partOne.concat(" is now");
                            // generate a query based on that relation
                            var query = relation.query();
                            Parse.Push.send({
                              where: query, // Set our Installation query
                              data: {
                                alert: outString1  
                              }
                            }, {
                              success: function() {
                                // Push was successful
                              },
                              error: function(error) {
                                // Handle error
                              }
                            });

                            var relation2 = object.relation("joined");
                            var partOnee = e.get("name");
                            var outString = partOnee.concat(" is now");
                            // generate a query based on that relation
                            var query2 = relation.query();
                            Parse.Push.send({
                              where: query2, // Set our Installation query
                              data: {
                                alert: outString 
                              }
                            }, {
                              success: function() {
                                // Push was successful
                              },
                              error: function(error) {
                                // Handle error
                              }
                            });


                            e.destroy();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });
    response.success();
});`

Since this method involves more than just a simple query and return (as it has the for loop among other things) I am a bit confused on how to implement the Parse ***Promise*** stuff. If anyone could assist me in how I should go about implementing the promise stuff it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

[Parse documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises) is very clear on how to use Promises and how to rewrite your pyramid code with `.then()` blocks instead.